# Example of normal random variable $X,Y$ s.t. $(X,Y)$ is not a Gaussian vector.

Tags: probability

Does someone has an example of r.v. $X,Y$ that are normal, $(X,Y)$ has a density, but $(X,Y)$ is not Gaussian ? I can't find such an example.

---

I saw as an example, $X$ is $N(0,1)$ distributed, $\mathbb P(S=1)=\mathbb P(S=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $Y=SX$. Then $X$ and $Y$ are normally distributed, but $(X,Y)$ is not Gaussian. But since $\mathbb P(X^2-Y^2=0)=1$, $(X,Y)$ has no density. So, this "counter-example" doesn't work. Any idea of a counter-example ?

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30159/is-it-possible-to-have-a-pair-of-gaussian-random-variables-for-which-the-joint-d?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192578/examples-when-vector-x-y-is-not-normal-2d-distribution-but-x-and-y-are

Comment: @leonbloy: I edited my question. In link I saw, $(X,Y)$ has no density, no ? (Maybe I didn't understaood very well some of your examples).

Comment: I dont understand, $(X,Y)$ has always a density (perhaps degenerate).

Comment: @leonbloy: $X:\Omega \to \mathbb R$ has a density w.r.t. $\mu$ (a measure on $\mathbb R$) if there is $f$ measurable s.t. $\mathbb P(X\in A)=\int_A fd\mu.$

Comment: In my exercise, density is w.r.t. lebesgue measure. @leonbloy

Comment: The example here is a proper (non-degenerate) density https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192578/examples-when-vector-x-y-is-not-normal-2d-distribution-but-x-and-y-are as also my example in the first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be Gaussian $N(0,1)$, let $S$ be independent of $X$, with $P(S=1)=P(S=-1)=1/2$, let $Y=SX$.
Then the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ is concentrated on the lines $y=\pm x$ in the plane,
and hence not jointly Gaussian.  But $X$ and $Y$ are each marginally Gaussian.

Another example: Let $\varphi(x,y)$ be the standard bivariate Gaussian density function (the joint density of iid $X$ and $Y$, with $X,Y\sim N(0,1)$).  Now let $\phi(x,y)=2\varphi(x,y)$ if $xy > 0$ and $0$ otherwise, and let $(X,Y)$ have $\phi$ as their joint density function.  It is easy to check that the margins of $\phi$ are those of $N(0,1)$ but yet $\phi$ is not itself a Gaussian density function.

Other examples with densities include all non-trivial convex combinations of $\phi$ and $\varphi$.  Such as $(\phi+\varphi)/2$ and so on.

In the first two  these examples the support of the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ is non-convex, and the support of any Gaussian distribution must be convex.  This makes checking that they are counterexamples easy.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question. I forgot the hypothesis that $(X,Y)$ has a density.

Comment: Any _you_ forgot to notice that my second example has a density.